# Django delete the old profile image cause this error in save() method The 'profile_img' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, django

I have profile model with an image field. The image will be cropped and resized When the user upload new one. I want to delete the old image using `post_save` signal.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_img',
                                    default='/profile_img/default.png',
                                    null=True,
                                    blank=True)

@receiver(post_init, sender=Profile)
def backup_image_path(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance._current_image = instance.profile_img


@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile)
def delete_old_image(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(instance, '_current_image'):
        if instance._current_image.path != instance.profile_img.path:
            instance._current_image.delete(save=False)
```

when the `_current_image` is deleted, the below save method raise the error.
the error comes from this line `image = Image.open(profile.profile_img)`

**forms.py**

```
class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    x = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    y = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    width = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    height = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ("profile_img",)

    def save(self):
        profile = super(ImageUploadForm, self).save()
        x = self.cleaned_data.get('x')
        y = self.cleaned_data.get('y')
        w = self.cleaned_data.get('width')
        h = self.cleaned_data.get('height')

        image = Image.open(profile.profile_img)
        cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w+x, h+y))
        resized_image = cropped_image.resize((300, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        resized_image.save(profile.profile_img.path)

        return profile
```

I don't know where my mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more than an hour debugging, I found out that deleting the current image shall be performed after handling the new image. `post_save` signal is executed before `save()` method so I got rid of `post_save` and performed deleting of the current image in the `save()` method after handling the new uploaded image.

```
def save(self):
        profile = super(ImageUploadForm, self).save()
        x = self.cleaned_data.get('x')
        y = self.cleaned_data.get('y')
        w = self.cleaned_data.get('width')
        h = self.cleaned_data.get('height')

        image = Image.open(profile.profile_img)
        cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w+x, h+y))
        resized_image = cropped_image.resize((300, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        resized_image.save(profile.profile_img.path)
        # keep the default pic
        default_img_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/profile_img/default.png'
        if profile._current_image.path != default_img_path:
            profile._current_image.delete(save=False)

        return profile
```

Hope this will help someone else.